# How to run code in parallel with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Hi i'm really new to threading and it's making me confused, how can i run this code in parallel ?

```
def search_posts(page):

    page_url = f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{page}'
    req = requests.get(page_url)
    res = req.json()
    
    title = res['title']
    
    return title



page = 1

while True:

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
        t = executer.submit(search_posts, page)

        title = t.result()

        print(title)

    if page == 20:
        break

    page += 1
```

Another question is do i need to learn operating systems in order to understand how does threading work?

Comment: Thanks so much for the following up, of course I will make sure to check it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` for every page. To do things in parallel, create only one `ThreadPoolExecutor` and use its `map` method:

```py
import concurrent.futures as cf
import requests


def search_posts(page):
    page_url = f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{page}'
    res = requests.get(page_url).json()
    return res['title']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex: 
        results = ex.map(search_posts, range(1, 21))
    for r in results:
        print(r)
```

Note that using the `if __name__ == '__main__'` wrapper is a good habit in making your code more portable.

---

One thing to keep in mind when using threads;
If you are using CPython (the Python implementation from `python.org` which is the most common one), threads don't *actually* run in parallel.

To make memory management less complicated, only *one* thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode in CPython. This is enforced by the Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL") in CPython.

The good news is that using `requests` to get a web page will spend most of its time using network I/O. And in general, the GIL is released during I/O.

But if you are doing calculations in your worker functions (i.e. executing Python bytecode), you should use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead.

If you use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` and you are running on ms-windows, then using the `if __name__ == '__main__'` wrapper is *required*, because Python has to be able to `import` your main program *without side effects* in that case.